# Automating repetitive tasks using bat script, does not continue to the next task

Tags: windows, batch-file, ant, automation, batch-processing

I want to automate a list of repetitive tasks in my development environment, that will in the long run save me time, hopefully, if I can do it right.

During development, I have to build my code, and deploy it to an already existing installation; There is a lot of zipping and unzipping involved.

I have most tasks down to its own .bat file; When run individually, it seems to be doing the job.

However - I would like to create one big bat file, that can be executed on demand, and each task will wait for the previous one to complete.

Now, my problem is, that after the very first task execute (running an ant build script) by entire bat script seems to exit the console, and it does not proceed on to the next one.

I tried inserting a wait command, but it does not solve the problem.

I would appreciate any advice on how to fix this problem.

Here is the code:

```
cd J:\playpit_2017\MyApp
echo %cd%
ant -f buildtest.xml

wait

echo "............build finished........................"
cd J:\playpit_2017\MyApp\build
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x  MyApp-1.7.0.7.zip -   oJ:\playpit_2017\MyApp\build\MyApp-1.7.0.7 * -r

wait
echo "............build file unzipped ........................"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ant` is a batch file, you need

call ant ...

so that the batch knows to return after the `ant` batch has finished.

You shoukd also check your spelling of `echo`.

There is no `wait`. Try `pause`.

Comment: I replaced the wait with pause, and put call in front of ant.  Now the cursor waits at the command line for user input (press enter) to continue. Can this somehow be made to continue automatically when the current task completes?

Comment: Certainly. Simply omit the `pause` directly after `ant`. That way, when `ant` completes, the `build finished` message should be produced and batch will continue from there. You should probably also put a `pause` just after the final echo`, not before. That way, you'll see the message and need to push a key before the batch closes (I'm assuming you're running it by clicking on it)

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I thought I had to put the wait/pause to make sure it would execute linearly. Turns out that is not necessary. This is gonna save me a ton of time :)